# How create a user and a profile with a single form in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-3.0

I have created a `Clients` model in `models.py` that is intended to be a Client (user) Profile.

```
class Clients(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Primeiro Nome")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name="Apelido")
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name="Morada")
    nif = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name="NIF", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')], primary_key=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=9, verbose_name="Telemóvel", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, verbose_name="Email")
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.first_name, self.last_name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Clientes"

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Clients.objects.create(user=instance)
            instance.profile.save()
```

This model is connected to the Django Users through a OneToOneField called `user`.

I created a form that is capable of adding data to the `Clients` model in `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Primeiro Nome")
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label="Apelido")
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Morada")
    nif = forms.CharField(max_length=9, label="NIF", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
    mobile = forms.CharField(max_length=9, label="Telemóvel", validators=[RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')])
    email = forms.CharField(max_length=200, label="Email")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'password1', 'password2', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'nif', 'mobile', 'email')
```

How can I, through this single form, add a `username` and `password` field so that, through the OneToOneField, it creates an user connected to this profile?

**EDIT**

The new version of the files above. Now, it creates the user, but all other fields for the `Clients` get passed empty.

My `views.py`

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
            user.first_name = form.cleaned_data.get('first_name')
            user.last_name = form.cleaned_data.get('last_name')
            user.address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
            user.nif = form.cleaned_data.get('nif')
            user.mobile = form.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
            user.email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('clientes')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'backend/new_client.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: If you google your question, you'll find [this](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html#sign-up-with-profile-model) tutorial which shows exactly what you need:  Subclass the [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm) (from django.contrib.auth.forms) so that all the functionality to create a user is already there.

Comment: @dirkgroten I have followed that tutorial, but the data doesn't get saved.

Comment: But that's not the code you're showing here. Subclassing the `UserCreationForm` is the correct approach, so go back to that, write the code as shown in the tutorial and edit your question with that code. The tutorial actually says that the form won't save the extra fields automatically. You need to do that in the view (I would actually do it in the form's `save()` method)

Comment: @dirkgroten I followed the tutorial again. I can now save the user, but all other fields get passed empty. I update the question.

Comment: show us your view

Comment: @dirkgroten just added it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208060/discussion-between-dirkgroten-and-joao-de-sousa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fields you added are just regular form fields, django doesn't know anything about where to save these values. So you need to override the form's `save()` method or save them in your view. Here's how to save them in your view, since this is what you started to do:

```
if form.is_valid():
    user = form.save()  # this creates the user with first_name, email and last_name as well!
    user.refresh_from_db()  # load the profile instance created by the signal
    user.clients.address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
    user.clients.nif = form.cleaned_data.get('nif')
    user.clients.mobile = form.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
    user.clients.save()
    login(request, user)
    return redirect('clientes')
```

Note: I don't do anything with `first_name`, `last_name` and `email` in the view, they are fields of the `User` model so they will already be saved automatically when you do `form.save()`. You should remove them from your `Clients` model.

Note 2: Renaming your `Clients` model to `Client` would make your code more readable. You should always use **singular** for your models. This way you can do `user.client.address` which makes more sense than `user.clients.address` since it's a one-to-one field.

Alternatively, you can override the form's `save()` method, which is a method I would prefer as I don't think the view should care about how to save the user's profile:

```
# in SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = super().save(commit)  # this creates the new user
    if commit:
        user.refresh_from_db()  # not sure if this is needed
        user.clients.nib = self.cleaned_data.get('nib')
        user.clients.address = self.cleaned_data.get('address')
        user.clients.mobile = self.cleaned_data.get('mobile')
        user.clients.save()
    return user
```